# From Orthogonality to DTFT

Tags: discrete-signals, dtft

I have met this question, but cannot prove it using DTFT definition.
Given: $g$ is a discrete sequence filter and:
$$ g \in l^2(Z)$$
$$\langle g_n, g_{n-2k} \rangle = \delta_{k}$$
Prove:
$$|G(e^{j \omega})|^2 + |G(e^{j(\omega + \pi)})|^2 = 2$$

Could you guys give me some direction on this one?
Thank a lot

Comment: just keep in mind that $$ G(e^{j(\omega+\pi)}) = G(e^{j\omega} e^{j\pi}) = G(-e^{j\omega})  $$

Comment: Hi @robertbristow-johnson I got stuck with 2k. I don't know how to interpret it in term of DTFT? Is it just a shift by 2k? then I add e^(jw2k), but this does not make any progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a few hints to get you started:

1. Define a sequence $x[k]=\langle g_n, g_{n-k} \rangle$ and write it as a convolution. From that it should be easy to find its DTFT $X(e^{j\omega})$ in terms of $G(e^{j\omega})$.
2. Next note that the given sequence is just a downsampled version of $x[k]$, so its spectrum is an aliased version of $X(e^{j\omega})$. That's how you end up with those two terms on the left-hand side of the frequency-domain representation.

Comment: Hi, I managed to follow your guide, so here what I have now:
$X(e^{jw}) = |G(e^{jw})|^2$. And we have $x_{2k}$ is a downsampled version of $x_k$. Then I have: 
$$
1/2(X(e^{(jw)/2}) + X(e^{j(w-2\pi)/2})) = 1
$$
$$
=> |G(e^{jw/2})|^2 + |G(e^{j(w-2\pi)/2})|^2 = 2
$$
I can only come here, so close to the result, but cannot move further. You have any other ideas transform it

Comment: Oh, could I do this?
Let $$w' = w/2$$

Then
$$
=> |G(e^{jw'})|^2 + |G(e^{j(w'-\pi)})|^2 = 2
$$
and
$$
 |G(e^{j(w'-\pi)})| = |G(e^{j(w'+\pi)})|
$$
Then I have the final result.
$$
|G(e^{jw'})|^2 + |G(e^{j(w'+\pi)})|^2 = 2
$$
I am not sure I could do like this? Because $w'$ is different than $w$

Comment: @hminle: Yes, you can do that. The result is true for any $\omega$.

Comment: wow, great sir. Thank you a lot